# Как вырезать css из фотошоп?

Tags: вёрстка, photoshop

Есть ли удобный инструмент для photoshop cc 2017, чтобы можно было быстро вырезать css-стили?
css-hat вроде как не работает для новой версии.
Или посоветуйте удобный инструмент, помимо фотошопа для вырезания css-стилей, для удобной вёрстки

Comment: А просто правой клавишей мыши на элемента и "скопировать css" - не подходит? Или нужно что-то что прямо вам и классы поставит, и сверстает дефакто за вас?

Answer (score 1):

Avocode отлично справляется с поставленной задачей.
Zeplin также хорошо работает.

Comment: Avocode штука платная

Comment: @KAGGDesign Фотошоп тоже :)

Comment: Это да . Есть такое )

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [CSS3Ps](http://css3ps.com) - абсолютно бесплатный плагин.

Использую его в Ps CS6. В FAQ'е говорится, что поддерживает PS Cs3 и выше, следовательно на CC так же должен корректно встать.